# Ionic Alert inside Interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm intercepting network response in order to give feedback about network error.

I can't get the ionic alert module to work.

I think that the problem is that ionic-alert use a promise which is not resolved, but I don't know what is wrong with my implementation.
The interceptor work. I can intercept all the request. The only problem is that  I cannot see the alert poupup.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, throwError, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RespinterceptorService {

  constructor(public alertController: AlertController) { }





  async mngerror(error: HttpErrorResponse){

    let input = error.statusText+error.name;

      const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Alert',
      subHeader: 'Subtitle',
      message: input,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });

    await alert.present();



    return throwError(error);
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


      return next.handle(req).pipe(
        catchError(this.mngerror)
      )
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must implement HTTPInterceptor in the class.

```
export class RespinterceptorService implements HTTPInterceptor {
```

Comment: Done, but is the same problem. I still don't see the poupup

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide your interceptor in your app module?

It should look like:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent],
imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
            { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: RespinterceptorService, multi: 
                true }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Also as mentioned before you have to implement HTTPInterceptor

Comment: Yes, the interceptor work correctly. I have some problem in calling the ionic-alert in the function in case of network error.